# Unable to run aws s3 sync as a cron job

Tags: backup, cron, amazon-s3

I'm having trouble running aws s3 sync as a cron job (on Ubuntu 16.04). Here's what I *am* able to do:

- Manually run the script in the /etc/cron.hourly directory using sudo
  (so it doesn't seem to be a problem with passing environment values)
- Manually run the script in a user directory without sudo
- Add either the script or the command itself to /etc/crontab - using
  either one of these:

  23 *    * * *   myusername aws s3 sync /home/myusername/temp/ s3://manning2323

  */1 *     * * * myusername /home/dbclinton/myusername/temp/s3script.sh

The problem with /etc/crontab, of course, is that it's liable to be overwritten by updates, so it's not good enough for my purposes.

Now here's what *doesn't* work:

- Leaving the script in cron.hourly and waiting for it to run
  automatically. It does run (as syslog and journalctl report), but the
  AWS CLI isn't providing me with any output that I can see so I have
  no way of knowing why the sync isn't happening. How do I know the
  sync isn't happening? Because new files aren't showing up in my S3
  bucket.
- I get exactly the same result with my own crontab adding this line
  through crontab -e

  47 18 * * * /home/myusername/temp/s3script.sh >> /home/myusername/cronlog.txt

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, because cron is a bit unpredictable in how it sees the PATH, I had to reference the aws binary in my script using its absolute address (/usr/local/bin/aws).

Comment: I'd suggest you run a script from cron, rather than having the commands directly within cron. That makes testing easier as well. This is how I do s3 sync with cron on Amazon Linux

Answer (score 0):

Before you enable your cron, you can have your aws credentials configure in your session like:

```
$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: yourAccessKeyID
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: yourSecretAccessKey
Default region name [None]: yourRegion
Default output format [None]: json
```

And so you can try with:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/./aws s3 sync local/dir s3://my-bucket/path
```

Be careful to configuring aws with user correct to cron

Comment: It is much better to use aws roles to handle your credentials than storing them on the instance itself.

Answer (score 0):

Cron is a little demanding and specific this is how i got to work it on two different ubuntu boxes using two different awscli install methods.

On Ubuntu 16.04 installed via PIP

```
sudo /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/aws s3 sync --region ap-northeast-1 /var/backups/ s3://BUCKET/backups
```

On Ubuntu 18.04 installed via apt-get
Run it with user **ubuntu**, when running with user **root** this will not work

```
sudo /usr/bin/aws s3 sync  --region ap-northeast-1 /var/backups/ s3://BUCKET/backups/
```

In both situations the --region is not required, but i paste it in for clarity

Comment: How did you use sudo in a crontab? And WHY?

Answer (score 0):

If you install aws console using snap then the absolute/executable address will be like /snap/bin/aws otherwise its looks like /usr/bin/aws . It can be different according to your installation.
You can find this path using `$ whereis aws` .

eg :

```
snap/bin/aws s3 sync --exclude "folder/path to exclude" pathtosync s3://bucketname/objects
```